# Create pdf: after mapping to unicode, display wrong

Tags: unicode, pdf-generation

I want to create a pdf file that display Thai language by text editor.After mapping to unicode and open the file, the texts display like it's white, but when i copy and paste to text editor it's normal(Thai unicode start from 0E01, in the sample I map 0000 0001 0002 -> 0E01 0E02 0E03).what is the problem please help.The code is below please make a try

```
%PDF-1.5
1 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text] /Font << /F1 2 0 R >>
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font /Subtype /Type0 /BaseFont /Arial /Encoding /Identity-H /DescendantFonts [3 0 R]/ToUnicode 14 0 R
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font /Subtype /CIDFontType0 /BaseFont /Arial /FontDescriptor 4 0 R
/CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (Identity) /Supplement 0 /CIDToGIDMap /Identity>>
/DW 1000 /W [231 389 500 631 631 500]
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Arial /Flags 7 /FontBBox [-170 -331 1024 903]
/ItalicAngle 0 /Ascent 723 /Descent -241 /CapHeight 709 /XHeight 450 /StemV 69
/Style << /Panose <010502020300000000000000> >>
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Length 6 0 R
>>
stream
BT
/F1 10 Tf 10 TL 0 Tr .05 Tc 1 0 0 1 27.3569560893065 760.695238095238 Tm
T* [<000000010002>]TJ
ET
endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
50000
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog /PageMode /UseNone /Pages 8 0 R /OpenAction [9 0 R /Fit]
>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages /MediaBox [0 0 595.2 841.8]
/Kids [
9 0 R
] /Count 1
>>
endobj
9 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page /Parent 8 0 R /Contents 5 0 R /Resources 1 0 R
>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<<
/Type /First 11 0 R /Last 12 0 R /Count 2
>>
endobj
11 0 obj
<<
/Title (Converted Report)
/Parent 10 0 R
/First 12 0 R /Last 12 0 R /Count -1 /Dest [9 0 R /Fit]
>>
endobj
12 0 obj
<<
/Title (1 / 1)
/Parent 11 0 R
/Dest [9 0 R /Fit]
>>
endobj
13 0 obj
<<
/Producer (PDF2AcR Ver 1.44 - Access Report PDF converter)
/CreationDate (D:20031218140436)
>>
endobj
14 0 obj
<< /Length 433 >>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry ( Adobe )/Ordering ( UCS )/Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
1 beginbfrange 
<0000> <005E> <0E01> 
endbfrange 
2 beginbfchar
<00A1> <00A1>
<005F> <0E01>
endbfchar
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
endstream
endobj
xref
0 15
0000000000 65535 f
0000000010 00000 n
0000000080 00000 n
0000000198 00000 n
0000000409 00000 n
0000000642 00000 n
0000001079 00000 n
0000001101 00000 n
0000001220 00000 n
0000001311 00000 n
0000001396 00000 n
0000001475 00000 n
0000001637 00000 n
0000001715 00000 n
0000001915 00000 n
trailer
<<
/Size 15
/Root 7 0 R
/Info 13 0 R
>>
startxref
50000
%%EOF
```

Comment: You added a **ToUnicode** mapping 0000... to 0E01... but that map only is relevant for text extraction. For glyph selection from the font you chose **Identity-H** so `000000010002` is displayed using the glyphs 0000, 0001, and 0002 from Arial. These clearly are not your Thai glyphs.

Comment: thks a lot for reply, actually I'm a newbie and not so clear about this.If there is away to fix please tell me, do I have to use embedded font, I dont wanna use this because it's in binary and can not be changed

Comment: I use this font AngsanaUPC-Bold and found that Thai text start from 0084,it's ok now. But I have to try so many times, can we find the code of font somewhere without trying?

Comment: Fonts usually contain information on which character a glyph represents. Thus, inspect your font before using it.